# Using external js library within vue.js app

Tags: javascript, canvas, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to use an external JS library that generates a drawing canvas (atrament.js) within a vue.js app.

I am not sure what is the right way of doing this. Right now I am just doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var main = new Vue({
        el: '#vueapp'
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">var atr = atrament("canvas", 500, 500);</script>
```

And with that the canvas is generated wherever I put the `<canvas></canvas>` tags.

However, this does not seem a very elegant option, and the `atr` var is not accessible for the vue app, for example for clearing the canvas. So, which is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should have `atr` variable as a vue [data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data) variable, like following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var main = new Vue({
        el: '#vueapp',
        data: {
          atr : atrament("canvas", 500, 500)
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now `atr` will be available in the vue app via `this.atr` and you can do required operations on it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had tried that already, but the canvas doesn't work when I do that. For some reason the canvas appears but I cannot paint on it. No errors are shown in the JS console. When doing this I am loading the vue app at the end of the html file, because if I put it on the <head>, then it says "<canvas> tags not found", so the canvas library is actually doing something.

Comment: @user1294122 can you create a fiddle of it?

Answer (score 0):

Since Vue is a component-based UI library, you should try to think in **components**.

Consider wrapping that canvas in a component and your parent element will talk to it via props and events. Vue has a very clean documentation for that: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html